# How do I pass complex types to Html.LabelFor?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

It doesn't work like this, the error is:

> Expected ","

```cs
    @Html.LabelFor(ViewBag.OrganizationDetails => (string)ViewBag.OrganizationDetails.AddressLegal, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

The `OrganizationDetails` is a class and the `AddressLegal` is a string (need its value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices.

The first, when using the `ViewBag`:

```
@using Models
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    OrganizationDetails details = ViewBag.OrganizationDetails;
}

@Html.LabelFor(m => details.AddressLegal, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

The second, use the strongly typed version of the [Html.LabelFor()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions.labelfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) by passing the model to the view:

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new OrganizationDetails() { AddressLegal = "Address" /* set another properties ... */};    
    return View(model);
}
```

And in the view:

```
@model Models.OrganizationDetails

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AddressLegal, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.AddressLegal)
```

Comment: Thanx, I didn’t know what to do this way - it’s very convenient:

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    OrganizationDetails details = ViewBag.OrganizationDetails; // local var, good!
}

Comment: I did this:
var model = new Views.FooViewModel();
            model.Organization = organization;
            model.OrganizationDetails = OrganizationDetails;
            model.OrganizationBuilding = OrganizationBuilding;
            
            return View(model);

Comment: @123 Иванов: Exactly! This is what usually we do is define one class that encapsulates all the data and pass it as model to the strongly-typed view.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```html
@model ParentModel

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Child.Name)
```

in your case should be:

```html
@model ViewBag.OrganizationDetails

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressLegal, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

or

```html
@model ViewBag

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrganizationDetails.AddressLegal, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

I haven't tried it.